# verb + a wounded body part?

Tags: vocabulary

I am looking for a verb that can take a wounded body part as its object.
It roughly means "give careful attention to" or "treat (a wounded body part) carefully/gently." Two examples I can think of are "nurse" and "baby."
Any alternatives?

Comment: What's wrong with either *nurse* or *baby* that you need something else?

Comment: I've found the word I was looking for. It's "favor," as in "She was favoring her left leg. [=she was walking carefully in a way that showed that her left leg was injured] "

But this is from an American dictionary. Do the British or Canadians use it this way?

Comment: Oh. You had a specific word in mind that you couldn't remember. Questions like that aren't good fits for this site—because we can't read your mind.

Comment: I was taking potluck; maybe someone thought the word "favor" is common in that context and could quickly mention it.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of words that could be appropriate, depending on how you give careful attention.  For example if you give attention by giving medical aid you could say "treat the wound" or "treat the wounded leg".  "Tend" is an alternative.

Your suggestion "favour" doesn't work, as you would favour the **un**wounded body part.  It means to use part of the body that isn't wounded, and so allow the wounded part to rest.

However you could say, "rest the wounded leg".

> My right knee is inflamed, so I'm resting it by favouring my left leg.

Comment: Hi! I upvoted your good answer! Favour means to protect or avoid using one leg, hand, arm, etc. because it is painful, injured, etc.:
He limped slightly, favouring his left leg.So we favour the wounded body part. Am I right or wrong? In your answer you said that we favour the unwounded body part. I am confused now and I don't know how to use the word favour as a verb.Can you help me, please?

Comment: I would use "favour the left leg" to mean "use the left leg more", because the right leg hurts.  But it's a pretty rare expression.

Comment: There's no need to leave a comment for every upvote. I sometimes leave a comment when I downvote (to say how a post can be improved) I rarely leave a comment when I upvote and never just to say "I upvoted".

Comment: Hi! 'He limped slightly, favouring his left leg.' That is an example of Cambridge Dictionary. In that example we favour the unwounded body part. Am I right?It's wrong to say that we favour the wounded body part. Am I right?

Comment: I'm begining to doubt myself now.

Comment: Hi! I have understood you! In the sentence 'He limped slightly, favouring his left leg' we favour the unwounded body part. It's wrong to say that we favour the wounded body part. Don't doubt yourself! You are right!I just asked you because you would tell me if I said something wrong!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Look after a wound

Attend a wound

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/nurse

Comment: I don't think you can use attend like that. Maybe you are thinking of *tend*? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tend